# Check the battery level of AltBeacon beacon

Tags: android, altbeacon

I have Radius Network, RadBeacon Dot beacon. It has AltBeacon standard.

I'm developing an Android app, and I need to monitor beacon battery level programmatically from my app.

If I use [android-beacon-library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) I can get the battery level?

If not possible, is there any other way to get the battery level of beacon programmatically from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the battery level using the Android Beacon Library like this:

```
long batteryLevelPercent = beacon.getDataFields().get(0);
```

Note that this simply fetches the data field of the AltBeacon standard, which on Radius Networks beacons is used for the battery level.  This may not work with beacons manufactured by other vendors.